# Dict() from list elements -- reducing time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more efficient manner to do what I am currently doing?

I have a set of list values, called `headers` that will be used for csv column headers. These values align with the names of data points in files I am parsing.

For example:

`headers = ['date', 'timeup', 'timedown', 'angle', 'flag']`

A file has record groups separated by 20 `*` so I parse each separation into groups:

```
>>> groups[0]:
['date=170821    timeup=3\ntimedown=5    angle=30\nflag=Y']
>>> groups[1]
['date=170821    timeup=13\ntimedown=25    angle=36\n']
```

I parse down even further to get element pairs such that:

```
for group in groups:
    lines = [line for line in group.split('\n') if line and '=' in line]
    items = [item.strip().split('=') for line in lines
             for item in line.split('  ') if item]
```

And get:

```
>>>items[0]
[['date', 170821], ['timeup', 3], ['timedown', 5], ['angle', 30], ['flag', 'Y']]
>>>items[1]
[['date', 170821], ['timeup', 13], ['timedown', 25], ['angle', 6]]
```

Now to build a dictionary from this and fill in `'NULL'` when an element is absent, I am doing:

```
for group in groups:
    d = {}
    lines = [line for line in group.split('\n') if line and '=' in line]
    items = [item.strip().split('=') for line in lines
             for item in line.split('  ') if item]
    for header in headers:
        try:
            x = [header in item for item in items].index(True)
            d[header] = items[x][1]
        except:
            d[header] = 'NULL'
```

Really this ends up being time consuming and sometimes I can have a `groups` object with over 800K groups, so already the top `for` is running at `O(N)`; `lines` and `items` are fast, but also run at `O(N)` and `O(N^2)` respectively (**correct?**). Then the last `for` runs at `O(N)`.

So in total I have `O(N) * O(N) * O(N^2) * O(N) = O(N^5)` and that's terrible!

**Question:**

> Is there a better way to determine if all the `headers` elements exist as `items` sublist elements and construct a `dict()`?

My shop isn't complaining because its doing a lot of work much faster than ever thought possible, but as the designer, I know this is flawed (though only due to the data points not always being consistent).

Comment: At first glance you can do... `d = dict.fromkeys(header, 'NULL'); d.update(items)`...

Comment: The complexity adds, not multiplies, it's O(n**2)

Comment: @SimonHobbs Which complexity adds? I thought nested loops multiply, i.e. a `for` within a `for` (assuming worst case) is `O(N^2)`? Further, what is meant by `**` in your time complexity notation?

Comment: @JonClements Only problem with that is it updates the dictionary with all the `items` pairs. The parsing I do to is only to get the `headers` pairs; sometimes values have a length greater than 2 and this fails.

Comment: @datta it'd be helpful if you included all the caveats in your question then. No point people spending time offering advice if it's going to be a case of: "Ahh, but what I didn't tell you is that... so that won't work"...

Comment: What about replacing `spaces` and `linebreaks` with `,`, `=` with `:`, `********************` with `},{`, add a `{` at the beginning and a `}` at the end and load it as json?
This can be done quite fast with command line tools.

Comment: @JonClements Apologies, but I thought it pretty clear that the `dict()` object will only hold the `headers` pairs since I iterate through them only to assign and nothing else.

Comment: @datta well... `d.update((k, v) for k,v in items if k in header)` and make `header` a set for lookup. It was reasonable clear what you were doing, but not obvious that you weren't needlessly doing it if `items` only contained a subset of header... (so could have been a valid optimisation)

Comment: @JonClements Is the `for` within `update()` not considered `O(N)`? Granted the `if` will filter down the size based on header to a certain factor, so there is some reduction, but is it any different than the `for` since I will only iterate `N` times over the contents of `headers`?

Comment: Could you include a sample of the raw text in the csv?  (I have a thought about using a different method of extracting the data from the file, but want to try it before suggesting.)

Comment: @JonClements I ended up using a variant of your implementation. If you want to post for answer but change to `d.update(item for item in items if item[0] in headers)`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is use a more efficient method to initialize the `dict`. Also, you can initialize headers as a `set` and then check the difference between the set of dictionary keys populated and populate the missing ones.

```
headers_set = set(headers)

for group in groups:
    d = dict([x.split('=') for x in line.split() if '=' in line])
    for missing_key in headers_set - set(d.keys()):
        d[missing_key] = 'NULL'
```

According to `%%timeit` tests, this method finishes this loop in 7.57 µs, whereas the loop you provide above takes 17 µs to execute. This code also is more Pythonic IMHO and seems easier to interpret.

Comment: Very good implementation; unfortunately some of the parsed data results in unpacking errors since the split may not result in an 1:1; that is out of my control so reducing the iteration checks is what I went with. Thanks though.